# Node.js elastic search filter using geopoint

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose

I'm attempting to filter data with geo distance.My mongoose schema is:

```
'use strict';
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var beautifyUnique = require('mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation');
    var mongoosastic = require("mongoosastic");

var schema = new Schema({
  vendor_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Vendor' },
  category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
  name: { type: String, required: 'Business Name is required' }, // es_indexed: true },
  contact: {
    contact_name: { type: String, required: 'Name is required' },
    email: { type: String, required: 'Email is required' },
    s_email: String,
    mobile: { type: String, required: 'Mobile No. is required' },
    s_mobile: String,
  },
  images: [{
    title: String,
    desc: String,
    key_large: String,
    url_large: String,
    key_thumb: String,
    url_thumb: String
  }],
  cover_image: String,
  description: String,
  seat_capacity: Number,
  float_capacity: Number,
  address: {
    address1: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    country: String,
    pin: Number
  },
  geometry: {
    type: [Number]
      // index: "2dsphere",
  },
  events: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event' }],
  highlights: [{ type: String }],
  advanced_percentage: Number,
  taxes: {
    food: Number,
    other: Number
  },
  cancellable: Boolean,
  time_slots: [{
    text: String,
    slot: String
  }],
  min_Order_quantity: String,
  outside_catering: Boolean,
  outside_decorators: Boolean,
  alcohol_allowed: Boolean,
  terms: String,
  aminities: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Aminity' }],
  sub_categories: [{ type: String }],
  status: { type: String, default: 'draft' },
  verifiedBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SuperAdmin' },
  verifyTime: { type: Date },
  isAvailable: Boolean,
  isBlocked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  blockedBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SuperAdmin' },
  blockReason: String,
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  updated_at: { type: Date },
  version: { type: Number }
});
schema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  hosts: [
    'localhost:9200'
  ]
});
schema.plugin(beautifyUnique);
// enables beautifying 
var Business = module.exports = mongoose.model('BusinessDetail', schema);

Business.createMapping({
  "mappings": {
    "businessdetail": {
      "properties": {
        "geometry": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, function(err, mapping) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error creating mapping (you can safely ignore this)');
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('mapping created!');
    console.log(mapping);
  }
});
```

And my search code is

```
BusinessDetail.search({
            "bool": {
              "must": {
                "match_all": {}
              },
              "filter": {
                "geo_distance": {
                  "distance": "200km",
                  "geometry": [lon, lat]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          function(err, business) {
            console.log('err:', err);
            console.log('data:', business);
            res.send({
              success: true,
              data: business
            });
          });
```

I've tried many combinations of filtering.But it give the error

> err: { Error: [query_shard_exception] field [geometry] is not a
>   geo_point field,  with { index_uuid="6e4ptkf0TFWwp1IN3tIRbA" &
>   index="businessdetails" }
>       at respond (C:\eventbucket\eb-server\node_modules\mongoosastic\node_modules\
>   elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:289:15)
>       at checkRespForFailure (C:\eventbucket\eb-server\node_modules\mongoosastic\n
>   ode_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:248:7)
>       at HttpConnector. (C:\eventbucket\eb-server\node_modules\mongoosa
>   stic\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\connectors\http.js:164:7)
>       at IncomingMessage.wrapper (C:\eventbucket\eb-server\node_modules\lodash\lod ash.js:4968:19)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)   status: 400,   displayName:
>   'BadRequest',   message: '[query_shard_exception] field [geometry] is
>   not a geo_point field, w ith { index_uuid="6e4ptkf0TFWwp1IN3tIRbA" &
>   index="businessdetails" }',   path:
>   '/businessdetails/businessdetail/_search',   query: {},   body:
>   '{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"geo_distance":{"di
>   stance":"200km","geometry":[88.36389500000001,22.572646]}}}}}',
>   statusCode: 400,   response:
>   '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"f
>   ield [geometry] is not a geo_point
>   field","index_uuid":"6e4ptkf0TFWwp1IN3tIRbA",
>   "index":"businessdetails"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"
>   all shards
>   failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"i
>   ndex":"businessdetails","node":"iQy-hWNlTnaiUL3cUlAWVQ","reason":{"type":"query_
>   shard_exception","reason":"field [geometry] is not a geo_point
>   field","index_uui
>   d":"6e4ptkf0TFWwp1IN3tIRbA","index":"businessdetails"}}]},"status":400}',
>   toString: [Function],   toJSON: [Function] } data: undefined

How to solve the error?